# Getting Spark Streaming performance metrics using data from rest API

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

I am new to using Rest Api for spark streaming resource usage computation, so I want to know some things regarding the data from rest

1. In `allexecutor` end point we have totalDuration and maxMemory  , if using dynamic allocation one specific executor was removed and then reallocated for some other task then does duration for this will add to its totalDuration or it would be overwritten.
2. For getting memory usage for Spark Streaming is it a correct way to use this rest API , or another way to do calculate memory used by Spark Streaming Application.